# Best way to manage shop products in an ecommerce store with React JS?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, frontend, mobx-react, recoiljs

I'm a beginner in react and need a bit of expert advice for managing products in react JS, I also need to implement filtration with various fields. May I store all products in state and perform the process manually or hit the API each time the page is loaded and while filtration is needed. What is the best way to achieve both?

Comment: Why don't you watch some tutorials and give it a head start ? If you find any issues, then ask in SO.

Comment: Almost every tutorial stores products statically in the state or in a static file. I've watched many tutorials on udemy, youtube, and coding bootcamps. What I'm asking for is the best way that is used in reality projects

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.